# How can I change the reference pattern in reference list (Number without square box)?

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, elsarticle

I am using Elsevier LaTeX template for preparation of manuscript. Everything is going fine, except the final bibliography list. It is in following format:

> [1] Alexander F.J., Chen S. and Sterling J.D., “Lattice Boltzmann thermodynamics,” Physical Review E. 47, R2249-R2252, (1993).

Instead of this, I want a format like

> 1. Alexander F.J., Chen S. and Sterling J.D., “Lattice Boltzmann thermodynamics,” Physical Review E. 47, R2249-R2252, (1993)

What should I do to get this type of reference list?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! If you're using the bibliography style from Elsevier (`elsarticle-num`) then presumably that is the style that Elsevier wants. Why change it?

Comment: There are several other bibliography styles, that Elsevier offers; though some Journals require a certain (or at least on eform a certain set of) bibliography style(s). My favourite a few years ago was `model1b-num-names` which did roughly what you wanted; but maybe they changed the naming system.